# Laravel API route not found 404

Tags: php, laravel

I have set up api.php as follows

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

/*
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
*/


Route::get('trip', 'TripController@getTrip');
```

I commented out middleware though I tried with it on first. Just to rule out that it is not affecting somehow.

in my TripController I have:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Trips;

class TripController extends Controller
{
    public function getTrip() {
        $jeekim = "JEEKIM";
        dd($jeekim);

        return response()->json(Trips::get(), 200);
    }
}
```

I have my database set up and a few data in it for testing. As I understand now, going to browser with
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/trip
should open this ?
But instead I get 404:
The requested URL was not found on this server.
I added variable in controller and dd just to see if I reach controller function but no.

I made sure i have a2enmod rewrite enabled.
I use ocean droplet cloud server, not on localhost. I have a testing route in web.php and it works, I can return a view. But this api route I cant get to work.

Comment: Run command `php artisan route:list.` It will show you list of available routes in your application.

Comment: Thank you for replies! Vipin's answer got me to solution. There were issues in my apache2.conf , more precicely in sites-enabled/000-default.conf
I got it to work

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### In your apache2.conf make sure you've  AllowOverride All not  AllowOverride none.

### Example-

```
<Directory /var/www/gloops/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

---

Comment: Thank YOU!!!!! there was some issues in sties-enabled/000-default.conf 
I got it to work :)

Comment: Great start @Vipin

Comment: I tried this but it is still not working

Comment: @Jeekim what changes have you done in 000-default.conf file?

Answer (score -2):

Move your `.htaccess` file from public folder to your application root and rename the `server.php` file at your application root to `index.php`.

Comment: This question already has an accepted answer. Can you explain why is your approach better?

Comment: @LajosArpad In fact, this is not a correct answer as this answer is changing how Laravel works, when fixing the user problem is not related to moving or editing anything related to Laravel itself...