# Laravel 8 404 api routes in production

Tags: php, laravel

I have never had this issue before, it was working perfectly and after I reinstalled the server I now got a `404` when I call my `0.0.0.0/api/students/show`.

I did `composer production` call on SSH to create latest autoloader. Cleared the cache for `php artisan`, the normal steps to setup a Laravel production app. But I still get `404` when I call the API endpoint.

Maybe the problems is something with `chmod` rights? Storage, etc. is already done...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62750155/laravel-api-route-not-found-404 did you check apache settings?

Comment: @keizah7 I already did that. Did not work

Comment: Other routes works correctly?
Please, run `php artisan route:list` to check if you have this api route

Comment: Look at my edit, thanks @keizah7

Comment: If an answer worked, click the gray check mark to the left of it.

Comment: @peterhillie I created an answer, you can mark it as best

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `apache2.conf` make sure you've `AllowOverride All` and not  `AllowOverride none`.

#### Example

```
<Directory /var/www/html/public>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

[Original Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62750282/11125098)

Comment: Don't forget to mention that you've multiple directory paths. Your base path and your direct path.

Answer (score 1):

You should not need to write `Directory` at all.

This is my working page custom `.conf` file on `sites-available` folder:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName matiaslauriti.dev
    ServerAlias www.matiaslauriti.dev

    Redirect 301 / https://matiaslauriti.dev
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName matiaslauriti.dev
        ServerAlias www.matiaslauriti.dev

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public

        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/matiaslauriti.dev/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/matiaslauriti.dev/privkey.pem
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

What I do have on my `apache2.conf` is default, I did not change anything:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Why is that your solution, instead of just changing .conf ?

Comment: Because if you install `apache2` and don't change anything in the `apache2.conf`, that config is the default, and any `.conf` you want to add to your apache, you have to add it in `sites-available`, and then enable that conf with the command `a2ensite NAME_OF_FILE` or make a symlink of that file to `sites-enabled` and restart or reload apache... that is the normal way... Never add sites in `apache2.conf` as that is not the correct way even if you can do it, you should not... this is basic `apache2` configuration...